# How can I get json from an API url on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to get text from a URL, it is an api url but it doesn't have any special arguments, I can use a static link. So if I put the link into the browser, its a blank page with just this text:

```
{"id":"hFXuavIS2Fu5TJs9WC9M-ylckZ-o4b21inxr5h8axKtT1HSH","accountId":"TIIQ3c3YnJc96-p4ASIt7spCeICawEWiBJKwwDYDm0WUP23TlGoum2cc","puuid":"I5Lb36kGyhZTq3ypf1fqh6tk3p3xVA8-l-6_EDA4a9imdXm_uXAvVs-Prc8hkRoKzGVT0vr55kZ1lQ","name":"CH0G4TH","profileIconId":949,"revisionDate":1588735966000,"summonerLevel":49}
```

Or different depending on the username.

I've tried using jquery for node, but it needs jsdom and I cannot get it to work at all, I get an error of `Error: Cannot find module './jsdom/living/generated/utils.js'`.

And using XMLHttpRequest, I don't get it. Sites show for calling for something specific inside the json, but I don't want that, just the whole thing, so skipping that and going directly to .send, it returns undefined.

This is what I've copied down from a site:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
        var getJSON = function(url) {

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'json';

            //(xhr.onload removed here because it was used for returning a callback, which I don't need.)

            xhr.send();
        }
        console.log(getJSON('url'))
```

And of course it returns undefined.

So I don't know, I'm not a coder, so I'm confused out of my head here. I'm sorry if this is really basic and i'm just being retarded.

Comment: Is this Riots APi (league of legends)?

Comment: yes i didn't mention because it seemed irrelevant, should be the same for any site or api

Comment: try in the browser, open console (F12) and run `fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json))` where `url` is the URL you use ... if using NodeJs, I would suggest [axios package](https://github.com/axios/axios) instead `axios.get(url).then(res =>console.log(res.data))` give it a try and let us know... - a very [simple example](https://i.imgur.com/ZXC9Gkl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this is riot games API from the json you provided (CH0G4TH, SummonerID).

-

There are quite a lot of library's/modules that you can use for riotsAPI but I would suggest: LeagueJS (a lot of other ones are garbage). since you said that you are not a coder I would suggest you use this rather then figuring it out yourself, makes it a lot easier.

### Note

You will need a riot-api key which you can get from this link:

https://developer.riotgames.com/

### Example Code:

```js
const LeagueJS = require('leaguejs');

// Here you should put your RGAPI code
const leagueJs = new LeagueJS("RGAPI-SylasReallyBeBrokenRn");

// I like to create a region variable (makes it easier to change later on)
const region = "oce"

// although you dont need to have a user variable I will be using one for example purposes
const user = "AIIChat" 

// Here I can get entries by name. It returns a body which I will log 
leagueJs.Summoner.gettingByName(user, region).then(user => {
 console.log(user)
})


// Returns {......}
```

### Endpoints:

( they dont really have docs)

- ChampionEndPoint

  ```
      - gettingRotations
  ```
- ChampionMasteryEndpoint

  ```
      - gettingBySummoner
      - gettingScoresBySummoner
  ```
- LeagueEndpoint

  ```
      - gettingChallengerLeague
      - gettingMasterLeague
      - gettingGrandMasterLeague
      - gettingLeagueById
      - gettingEntriesForSummonerId
      - gettingLeagueEntriesForSummonerId
      - gettingEntries
  ```
- LolStatusEndpoint

  ```
      - gettingShardData
  ```
- MatchEndpoint

  ```
      - gettingById
      - gettingTimelineById
      - gettingListByAccount
      - gettingListByAccountWithoutPagination
      - gettingRecentListByAccount
      - gettingIdsByTournament
      - gettingByIdForTournament
  ```
- SpectatorEndpoint

  ```
      - gettingActiveGame
      - gettingFeaturedGames
  ```
- SummonerEndpoint

  ```
      - gettingByName
      - gettingByAccount
      - gettingById
      - gettingByPUUID
  ```

Comment: Okay, that is so much easier. I looked around for riot api tutorials or examples but I couldn't find any so I assumed you just use standard javascript libraries already avaliable to get the json. Thanks a lot man